# How to programatically choose level in indoor maps via Android Maps SDK

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

Is there a way to programatically select a level in indoor maps using Google Maps Android SDK

Here is what we are trying to achieve:

1. Android app lists different stores in a particular premises (for which indoor maps are available)
2. Android app has a feature to locate a particular store on the MAP
3. Android app to use Maps SDK to put a marker on that particular store and if that store happens to be on level 2 (non default level) choose level 2 programatically

Any help regarding this is appreciated !! Happy to provide any further information that may be required.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a list of stores but you can programmatically select a floor of the building. Therefore first you have to zoom in to the position `LatLgn pos` where the building is.

```
map.moveCamera(pos, 18));
```

Afterwards you retrieve the focused building and select the level you want

```
IndoorBuilding building = map.getFocusedBuilding();
    if(building != null) {
        List<IndoorLevel> levels = building.getLevels();
        //active the level you want to display on the map
        levels.get(1).activate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Chec this links for more information
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/IndoorBuilding

or this
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/IndoorLevel